# Complex integral over surface of sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, surface-integrals

How do we go about computing the integral $$\int_{|x|=t} \frac{e^{ikx}}{|x|} d\sigma$$ where $d\sigma$ is the measure of the sphere of radius $t$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$? My approach thus far has been to rewrite
$$\int_{|x|=t} \frac{e^{ikx}}{|x|} d\sigma = \int_{|x|=t} \frac{cos(kx)+isin(kx)}{t} d\sigma \\
= \int\int\int \frac{cos(kx)+isin(kx)}{t} (t^2)drd\theta d\phi$$ but am getting stuck reducing the calculation from here.

Comment: Hint (1): choose you spherical coordinates such that "north" is in the direction of the vector $k$. This way, the scalar product $k\cdot x$ is equal to $\cos(\theta)|k| |x|$. (Also the $\phi$-integral will be trivial to do).

(2) the integrand does not depend on $t$, so you can pull it out of the integration.

Comment: I see how integrating over the surface makes the radius of t fixed so we need not integrate over that, but I don't fully understand your comment about "choosing north". Do you mean replacing $\phi$ by $\phi - k$ somehow?

Comment: "$\phi-k$" does not make sense. $\phi$ is a number, $k$ is a vector. Here is what I meant: Usually, spherical coordinates are defined in a way such that $\phi$ is rotation around the z-axis, and $\theta$ is an angle measured from the z-axis. But this is a choice. You can choose your spherical coordinates in such a way that $\phi$ is rotation around the vector $k$ (which is fixed), and $\theta$ is an angle measured from $k$. Its like a rotated version of normal spherical coords. You dont need to write any any complicated formulas. The only relevant is how to express $k\cdot x$.

Comment: I see, so the problem can be reformulated as $$t \int_0^{\pi} \int cos(kx) + isin(kx) d \theta d \phi$$ where we then replace $cos(kx)$ by $\frac{kx}{|k||x|}$ from dot product definition?

Comment: well, this is getting to long for the comment section. Just posted you an answer instead

Comment: There is something wrong in your expression. How are you exponentiating a vector?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, we choose spherical coordinates in "$k$-direction", so that $k\cdot x=|k||x|\cos(\theta)$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|=t} \frac{e^{ikx}}{|x|} d\sigma
&= \frac{1}{t}\int\int  t^2\sin(\theta)e^{i \cos(\theta)|k|t} d\phi d\theta
\end{align}
Note that he "$t^2\sin(\theta)$" came from the variable change. Furthermore:

- The $\phi$-integral is now trivial (nothing depends on $\phi$).
- we can substitute $\cos(\theta)=u$ with $\sin(\theta)d\theta=du$

Therefore the remaining integral will be $\int e^{ui|k|t}$. Given that $i|k|t$ is just a constant, this should be doable I hope ;)

Comment: ah this makes sense now, thanks! Shouldn't the the spherical coordinate integration have a $t$ multiplied out front, rather than $t^{-1}$? Thus, the final integration would have that variable cancelling out?

Comment: oh, yeah. There is a factor $t^2$ missing, which makes it $t$ overall. Fixed it.